# iOS remote notification type

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any apns push that can wake application up, do something in background and keep silence?

I found two solutions, but still not perfect:

1. Background notification. It can wakes app up in the background and gives it time to do something, but Apple doesn’t guarantee the delivery and it can't work after device is rebooted
2. UNNotificationServiceExtension. It can wakes app up and do something in the background, even if the device is rebooted. But, it can't be silent.

Our flow on iOS was:

1. Receive remote notification
2. Download data from server
3. Determine whether to notify from the content of the data

In iOS 12, our solution is PushKit, but it has some restrictions in iOS 13 now, so we have to make some changes.

Could anyone give me some advice, please? Thanks.

Comment: You already found the correct options. Just download the data when the user foregrounds the app instead.

Comment: As Claus said, you have listed the only options available for receiving a notification and running in the background. One thing that might help with some cases, though I haven't investigated yet, is using background app refresh. It won't be triggered by remote notifications, but will run in the background.